# Alternate the Angular material icon by clicking

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a material table, in which there is a column called status (see the image) [image]

What I need is by clicking on the material icon, the icon should be alternate depending on the value set from the 'ts' file. I am using a public variable to change the icon. However, as I am using only one variable, the effect is taking place for all the rows. Moreover, if I control it with the id of the clicked item, the previous clicked values (icons) are replaced by the old values (icons). For your information, I am showing and saving data through observable (API). So no way to take the value from API and show it instantly in the list. Bellow is the code of the both HTML and 'ts':

```js
onClick(event, row) {
  if (event.srcElement.innerText === 'panorama_fish_eye') {
      this.statusIconTextTrue = 'check_circle';
      taskStatus = 'FINISHED_COMPLETED';
      archived = true;
      timeFinishedActual = new Date().getTime();
    } else {
      this.statusIconTextTrue = 'panorama_fish_eye';
      taskStatus = 'CREATED';
      archived = false;
      timeFinishedActual = null;
    }
}
```

```html
<mat-icon (click)="onClick($event, element)">
                  {{ statusIconID == element.taskuuid && statusIconTextTrue ? statusIconTextTrue : statusIconText  }}
                </mat-icon>
```

I am struggling for couple of days to put the right logic to cope with issue. Any thoughts on this or may be some other solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easiest is to simply maintain a property on `row`. That will also help you out of the poor situation to check for innerText. There are plenty of undefined variables in your code, the should live in `row` as well

Comment: Thanks @chrispbacon for your comment. The 'row' variable holds the value that API serve from the initial loading. So by clicking we can only get that value. Sorry for the other undefined variables. Although those are not actually undefined. Those are used for saving purpose to API. Can you give me some more details to focus? Thanks again

Comment: Put the above code into a stackblitz demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yasir, use the value of "status". The click only change the status, see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p8zmmd?file=app/table-basic-example.html)

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="status">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
    <td (click)="element.status=!element.status" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-icon>
            {{ element.status?'check_circle' : 'block'  }}
        </mat-icon>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

If "status" is not in the data you received, you can add easy after subscribe to the service. Imagine you has a service that return an array of data with an unique property date, you can make something like

```
dataService.subscribe((res:any)=>{
   res.forEach(x=>{
      x.status=false;
   })
   this.data=res
})
```

NOTE: in the e.g. the status has only two values "true" and "false", it's the reason that the click becomes so easy like `(click)="element.status=!element.status"` can be has two values 'finish' and 'unfinish' then the column becomes like

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="status">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
    <td (click)="element.status=element.status=='finish'?'unfinish':'finish'
        mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-icon>
            {{ element.status=='finish'?'check_circle' : 'block'  }}
        </mat-icon>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Hi @Eliseo, thanks a lot for your answer. The good news is that it is working for me :-). I admire your efforts because you hit the nail on the head although my code is not that much nifty.